# Query To Return Multiple Values From A Single Column Based On Value Of Another Column

Tags: sql

I have a table with an EntryDate and a ChecklistDay column. They are Date and Integer columns. I want to return two columns, one named StartDate and another EndDate, both getting their values from the EntryDate column.  StartDate would be returned from...

```
SELECT EntryDate AS StartDate FROM TABLE WHERE ChecklistDay = 1
```

EndDate would be returned from...

```
SELECT EntryDate AS EndDate FROM TABLE WHERE ChecklistDay = 10
```

Now I only want to return a row if a value is returned for both StartDate and EndDate, meaning that a ChecklistDay must have both values 1 and 10 in order for it to select the two EntryDates and return a row.  What kind of query do I use here?

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: How would one row from the table relate to another row in the same table?  Is there some common ID that we can join through?

Comment: There is a ChecklistEntryID PK, and also a ProjectID FK. I need to find the start date and end date for each project. If an entry for ChecklistDay 1 and 10 are in the table, then that part of the project is complete and I need to count the days it took to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join to the same table twice.

```
select startDt.EntryDate as StartDate,
       endDt.EntryDate as EndDate
from table startDt
inner join table endDt
on startDt.id = endDt.id
where startDt.ChecklistDay = 1
and endDt.CheckListDay = 10
```

Comment: Understood.  That's why I listed "table" twice, but aliased it.  This is what you wanted.  You can join a single table to itself.

Comment: I don't see the alias for table in this query. Only aliases for columns. In any case, there is an error in design of this database - here is no bullet proof way to say if two rows are actually a pair of related data.

Comment: Elmo Bill is aliasing table as startDt and table as endDt, remember that [as] is optional

Comment: If you can't relate the rows, then given 4 start dates and 4 end dates, how can you return only 4 rows?  Or would you expect the cross product of each start date with each end date, yielding 16 rows?

Comment: Okay, now I see. Don't you guys know, that `table` is a reserved word in SQL? It'se even coloured in the code - I didn't look at it at all because of the colour and got confused. I know that the same bug is in the question, but my statement includes the question author as well.

Comment: I used "table" because that's what was used by the OP.  Trying to answer with the syntax provided.

Comment: @BillGregg, I've upvoted your comment about `cross product` - this is exactly what I'm afraid of, when I say `there is an error in design of this database`.

Comment: Well there is no solution to bad data.  If you can't relate one row to another then you are stuck.  As a human being looking at the data, how do you relate them?  Is it possible for a human to distinguish related rows?  If so, then you should be able to "code" the relationship.

Comment: @BillGregg, surely it's not my question and not my problem. But I'm afraid that no matter how good query we will prepare, it won't work as he expects on bad schema.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo TABLE was an example of the actual table name, it's not actually named TABLE. I'll correct that in an edit. Also, how could I make the design more efficient? I want to allow a user to enter a particular day that they are at on a project sheet. So if milestone 1 starts on checklistday 1, then when they hit the beginning of checklistday 10 it commences milestone 2, indicating that milestone 1 took the number of days from the date they started on checklistday 1 to 10. Perhaps I should begin another thread, this probably isn't too clear.

Answer (score 0):

Would this help:

```
Select CASE ChecklistDay WHEN 1 THEN EntryDate ELSE NULL as StartDate,   
CASE CheckListDay WHEN 10 THEN DateAdd(day, ChecklistDay, StartDate) ELSE NULL END as EndDate   
from Table
```

Comment: He wants to return a result row only for pair of rows, where one has a checklistday = 1 and another checklistday = 10. Your answer is clever, but doesn't check if the complementary row exists.

Answer (score 0):

This should run in any ANSI compatible DBMS (Oracle, MySql, Sql Server, Postgresql, Informix, DB2, etc)

```
SELECT
   CASE ChecklistDay WHEN 1 THEN EntryDate ELSE NULL END as StartDate
 , CASE CheckListDay WHEN 10 THEN EntryDate ELSE NULL END as EndDate
FROM
   TABLE
;
```

Comment: He wants to return a result row only for pair of rows, where one has a checklistday = 1 and another checklistday = 10.

Comment: You are right @ElmoVanKielmo, I misunderstood the question, then Bill Gregg answer is correct.